# Node App runs on Server only with nodemon

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pm2, nodemon, mongodb-atlas

i developed a little api with node on my local machine using nodemon and mongodb.atlas service.

Everything is fine, now i upload it to the server and try to get it running.

Nginx config is fine.

If i run nodemon, app is working over the domain like expected.

But if i use forever or pm2, i get 502.

pm2 gives me error log -  MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed.

Can not understand why there is a mongodb connection problem.
Server ip is whitelisted at atlas and as i said, everything works like charm with nodemon.

```
mongoose.connect(
  'mongodb+srv://<name>:<password>@marketing-api-bvzel.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
      {useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true}
);
```

Comment: <name>:<password> are replaced with the correct credentials btw.

Comment: Also tested api calls with postman over the domain when it runs on nodemon. Everything works, also writing into the mongodb.atlas service.

Comment: can you show us what package.json contains

Comment: Here is package.json

`{
  "name": "marketing-api",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.4",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.4"
  }
}`

Comment: I also run a new npm install after upload to make shure that everything is installed as should.

Comment: you mentioned that you used nodemon ?I don't see it inside your packages or even inside your script commands

Comment: nodemon isn't something that you wouold have in your package.js. It is just a dev tool that restarts server anytime file has changed so that you dont have to stop and start node everytime by hand.

But turns out, that it's got even worse.

I now created a new app with express-generator direct on the server without changing anything.
And here it's the same. With nodemon, i can access the page over the domain. 
Also with npm start.
Running it with pm2, 502.
So at this point, i'm totaly confused.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is so simple but really hard o find.

If you use an app generated by **express**, you have to use **pm2 start bin/www** instead of pm2 start app.js.

That simple.